# Issue in dropdown using ajax concept

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

In the below code i am working on dropdown list using ajax concept.My issue is i can able to return the values in comma separted and in callback method it the msg parameter value is object object.Pls help me to solve the issue.The second dropdown value is not binding.

```
 $(document).ready(OnReady);

        function OnReady() {
           //Handle the change event for the drop down list
            $("#ddlLocation").change(onChange);
        }

        function onChange() {
            //create the ajax request
            $.ajax
        (
            {
                type: "POST", //HTTP method
                url: "NewIndent.aspx/OnContinentChange", //page/method name
                data: "{'continentName':'" + $("#<%=ddlLocation.ClientID%>").val() + "'}", //json to represent argument
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: callback,
                error: onError
            }
        );

        }

        //Handle the callback on success
        function callback(msg) {
            alert(msg);//it shows object object

            var countries = msg.split(';');
            var length = countries.length;


            document.getElementById('<%=ddlProduct.ClientID %>').options.length = 0;


            var dropDown = document.getElementById('<%=ddlProduct.ClientID %>');
            for (var i = 0; i < length - 1; ++i) {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = countries[i];
                option.value = countries[i];

                dropDown.options.add(option);
            }
        }

        //Handle the callback on error
        function onError() {
            alert('something went wrong');
        }





[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string OnContinentChange(int continentName)
        {
            MastersClient objProductName = new MastersClient();
            DataSet dsProduct = objProductName.GetLocationProductMap(continentName);
            DataTable firstTable = dsProduct.Tables[1];

            string result = string.Empty;

            foreach (DataRow r in firstTable.Rows)
            {
                result += r["ProductName"].ToString() + ";";
            }

            return result;//return all the values in comma separated
        }





<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLocation" runat="server" style="width:40%;"  EnableViewState="true"        onchange="onChange()" />
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProduct" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProduct_SelectedIndexChanged"  AutoPostBack="true" Style="width: 100%; height:23px" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a `Json object` in return which is a combination of `key value pair`
so retrieve the data on `success` as

```
 success: function (object) {
                    $.each(object, function (key, val) {
                    alert(key);alert(val);
   })
 }


 function callback(msg) {
        alert(msg);//it shows object object

        var countries = msg.split(';');
        var length = countries.length;


        document.getElementById('<%=ddlProduct.ClientID %>').options.length = 0;
        var dropDown = document.getElementById('<%=ddlProduct.ClientID %>');
        $.each(msg, function (key, val) {                 
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.textContent = key;
            option.value = key;
            dropDown .appendChild(option);            
     })
    }

    //Handle the callback on error
    function onError() {
        alert('something went wrong');
    }
```

Comment: how can i bind values to second dropdown?

Comment: In alert it return sunrise;rice;jaggery;goldwinner;

Comment: so what in those you want to populate? and which are keys and which  are values please specify

Comment: the key is d the values are  sunrise;rice;jaggery;goldwinner;

Comment: so you want to bind these in ddl?

Comment: Can't call callback method

Comment: please dont use scuccess function with call back

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
dropDown.appendChild(option);
```

instead of

```
dropDown.options.add(option);
```